# Cyberpunk short story where Soviet brain-in-bottle pilots fly aircrafts

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, cyberpunk

In a piece from his non-fiction collection [*Distrust That Particular Flavor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distrust_That_Particular_Flavor) (2012), William Gibson writes:

> A friend of mine wrote a short story, a decade ago, in which the protagonists were Soviet equivalents of Predator drones, but literal cyborgs: small fighter aircraft controlled by brain-in-bottle onboard pilots, with very little left in the way of bodies.

The piece ("Googling the Cyborg") was originally written in 2008, which suggests that the said story was written circa 1998. AFAIK, the list of well-known friends of Gibson who happen to be scifi (and mostly cyberpunk) authors includes Bruce Sterling, John Shirley, and Lewis Shiner (among possibly others).

Any idea about which is the story and the author?

Edit: as correctly pointed out in the comments below by DavidW, there seems to be some inconsistency in the inferred dates, since the Soviet Union had been dismantled already since 1991...

Comment: What in that description makes you think that the short story is cyberpunk?

Comment: @Valorum The short description sounds (to me at least) like spot-on the cyberpunk tropes of the era, plus the info that the author is a friend of Gibson's; I might be wrong on this though (but again, I am not aware of any *formal* definition of cyberpunk).

Comment: Note that if it's truly *Soviet* drones, that would place the story no later than, say, 1992.

Comment: @DavidW that's a nice point (and possibly even earlier, Soviet Union was dismantled in 1991)

Comment: @DavidW Could be alternative history, could be set in a future where the Soviet Union has been restored.

Comment: @user14111 Both of those are valid points; I guess I simply didn't associate the alt. history idea with most of the "cyberpunk" that was written during its heyday.

Comment: @DavidW indeed, I am not aware of any alt-history cyberpunk work of the era either

Comment: John Shirley had a resurgent Soviet Union in "A Song Called Youth", but I don't remember any "brain-in-bottles" involved

Comment: In  Cemetery World by Clifford Simak there are two war machines with "five men who were willing to sacrifice their bodies and their positions as human beings to man a war machine" ("four minds" in the second machine. First machine is American and the second is Russian).

Comment: [tvtropes - BrainInAJar](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BrainInAJar)

Answer (score -2):

Sounds similar to Goliath by Neil Gaiman, written as a tie-on to The Matrix, and collected in Fragile Things.  Summary is here: https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Goliath_(pilot)

Comment: Thanks; looks like a nice story, but I don't think it is the requested one.

Comment: Sorry, but this story is *nothing* like the story described above.